# How to get data returned from database that contains either a date or returns nothing in to a view in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my first time having to query a DB stored procedure in .Net MVC. The procedure returns either zero rows (meaning user has never entered data) or one row with one column called [When] that contains a date.

I have a DataHelper Class that I wrote the following method in to query the stored procedure.

**DataHelper Class Method**

```
public static DataSet Measurements_GetLastMeasurement(Guid UserID)
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(CONN_STRING))
    {
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.CommandText = "dbo.Measurements_GetLastMeasurement";

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }
}
```

This was pretty straight forward, it's passing the data into the controller and then to the view where I get lost. If the result of this query returns a date I want to print that date to the screen. if it returns null I want to store the null value and run a condition on it. Here is how I am currently setting up part of the controller method to handle this.

**Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult ChartView()
{  
    var authHelper = new stuff.for.auth();
    var userSession = authHelper.GetUserSession();    

    // get users last data entry date
    DataSet ds = Measurements_GetLastMeasurement(userSession.UserIDNative);
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DateTime lastEntryDate = dr["When"];
    }

    ViewData["LastEntryDate"] = lastEntryDate;

    return PartialView();
  }
```

Then from in the view I would think I should be able to access the data by setting the ViewData["LastEntryDate"] to a variable and displaying it in the html or using Javascript to check and see if the value is null. Any clarification or guidance is hugely appreciated!

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: Sorry I had hit enter by accident before finishing the question @Brad M .

Comment: I suggest checking to see if the ds is null in the controller and deal with is there, instead of passing it all the way to the view and dealing with it through JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The variable must be defined outside of your foreach loop for the variable in order for it to be in scope when you set ViewData["LastEntryDate"] = lastEntryDate;
2. The variable must be a DateTime? (aka Nullable<DateTime>) in order for null to be a valid value

Try this:

```
        DateTime? lastEntryDate = null;
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            lastEntryDate = (DateTime?)dr["When"];
        }

        ViewData["LastEntryDate"] = lastEntryDate;
```

Comment: I don't know for sure how this code will act with a null from the database.  You may require additional code to convert DbNull to null.

Comment: Seemed to work, Thanks! When a user has no entered data the lastEntryDate returns null which I can test against.